# How to add a side menu with NativeScript + Angular 2 project?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i'm whiling to know how to add a side menu on my current NativeScript + Angular 2 project, I know that has a side menu template, but i started it as blank project and i'm wonder how to add this feature.

Comment: Could you post some of your code here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use Telerik UI for NativeScript (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui), please refer to this guide on how to integrate:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started

You can see an example of how to wire it up here:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but in the latest blogpost from Nativescript this one was mentioned:
https://github.com/ntrp/nativescript-ng2-drawer-seed