# How to integrate nativecript plugin [Nativecript and Angular 2]

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I found this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sidedrawer

Is possible to implement it in angular 2 nativescript project? Could you show me some example?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778655/how-to-add-a-side-menu-with-nativescript-angular-2-project?rq=1 There is a seed project link at the bottom.

Comment: KTCO, that's a different plugin than the one Vladimir linked to, but I use the one you mentioned as well.